# XMLStarlet Installation on HP-UX

Tags: hp-ux, xmlstarlet

I am not able to install XMLStarlet 1.4.2 or 1.5.0 on HP-UX. When I run the ./configure script it gives the following error

```
./configure[459]: sed:  not found.
./configure[471]: expr:  not found.
./configure[474]: sed:  not found.
./configure[478]: sed:  not found.
```

I have tried on RHEL6 and it installed successfully but unable to install it on HP-UX.

Comment: You need `expr` and `sed` (and possibly other utilities) on HP-UX.

Comment: @devnull `sed` is already working, dont know why its giving sed error, `expr` is missing i think

Answer (score 0):

the user did not have access that is why I was getting the error.